# html helper ValidationMessageFor in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Let's say we have a viewmodel which is

```
public class NewCustomerViewModel
{
   public IEnumerable<MembershipType> MembershipType { get; set; }
   public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

and we have a form.cshtml to create/edit customer and below is some html helpers

```
 @Html.LabelFor(e => e.Customer.Name)
 @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Customer.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Customer.Name)
```

So Let me rephrase it in a simple way:

1.When creating a customer, when the code is executed to @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Customer.Name), no error even there is no name for customer

2.When saving a customer without names (posting the form and go back to the same view), when the code is executed to @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Customer.Name), error appears because the customer has no name.

So my questions is, why there is no error in the first time when I was creating a new customer? since the new customer has no name (I'm typing customer name into the textbox), why there is no error brought by @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Customer.Name)?

Comment: What do you mean " but why the error message does't turn up when creating a new customer?"

Comment: @CodingYoshi I mean when I create a new customer, apparently we need to type details, so the new customer has no name when we load the form, then why ValidationMessageFor doesn't prompt an error?

Comment: it will show the error when you click the button to submit the form.

Comment: @CodingYoshi when I click submit button, the control just throws the same form.cshtml view and now the error will show but why it ddin't show in first place, does ValidationMessageFor only works at post method becase the first request is a get request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the browser requests a page, the html is returned to the browser. It will have a label, and a textbox for the customer name. The user will have a chance to enter the customer name and then submit the form. If the user does not enter the customer name, and clicks the button to submit the form, then the error will show. Depending on how this is setup, the error may show up without even leaving the browser. This is called client side validation which is done with jQuery or pure javascript.

If there is no client side validation, it will get to the server and at the server, the asp.net mvc engine will use model binding to populate your model. Then it will use the attributes you have on your model and set the `ModelState` property to either valid or invalid. You will need to write code in the controller and do something about it if it is invalid:

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // Now MVC will create the error message and send 
    // the view back to the browser
    return View(model);
} 

// Model is valid so save to database or do whatever you need to.
```

Keep one thing in mind: Even if you have client side validation, you should always do validation on the server side because client side validation may not trigger if the user has turned off javascript. Or a savvy user can find ways to go around your validation.

**EDIT**

In a comment to this answer, you asked:

> what's the relationship between ModelState and ValidationMessageFor?Did ModelState bind a error and pass it the view then ValidationMessageFor recognise it?

The signature for `ValidationMessageFor`, the one you have used in your question is this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression);
```

And here is how you are using it:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Customer.Name)
```

See the second parameter `expression` is of type `Expression`. MVC uses that information to tie the `Customer.Name` to the validation message. When you pass a model to the view, MVC will look in the `ModelState.Errors` for any errors related to the `Customer.Name` property. So who puts the error in the `ModelState.Errors` collection?  The default DataAnnotations model binder will fill it with validation errors using the attributes you have decorated you model with. It will then render the appropriate HTML so the browser can show it to the user.

This is why in first case when the browser simply requests the page, the `Errors` collection will be empty, so MVC will not render the HTML to be shown as error. However, when the form is posted, if the user did not do everything required to pass validation, then MVC will add the error to the `ModelState.Errors` collection.

I think you confusion, partly, comes from why do we even need the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Customer.Name)` when we are displaying the page for the first time to be filled out by the user. The answer: We do not need it (not really but keep reading). We can just send a different view after the form is submitted and make sure that view has the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Customer.Name)`. I have not seen such a design and it will lead to code duplication (but the duplication can be avoided...anyways lets stay on point).

Note I said *not really but keep reading*, well here is why we may want to have  `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Customer.Name)` even when displaying for the first time. In most cases the validations can be done on the client side (it will need to be done again on the server side) and this is a better experience for the end user. In that case, it is nice to have the hmtl already in the view and then show/hide the error, decorate it using CSS through javascript or jQuery. If the HTML is not there, then it will need to be generated on the client side. Actually you will not even need to write code for showing/hiding the error: Open the `\Scripts\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` file and search for “data-val” and you’ll see that it uses the data-val-*, input-* and field-* CSS classes to display/hide validation messages on the client.

Comment: You mentioned that using !ModelState.ISValid, MVC will create the error message, so what's the relationship between ModelState and ValidationMessageFor?Did ModelState bind a error and pass it the view then ValidationMessageFor recognise it?